# PLS-00103 in a procedure

Tags: oracle, stored-procedures

I am working on some procedures to insert a new customer. This is my code:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE ADD_CUST
(
 P_CUST_ID       CUST_INFO.CUST_ID%TYPE,
 P_CUST_F_NAME   CUST_INFO.CUST_F_NAME%TYPE,
 P_CUST_L_NAME   CUST_INFO.CUST_L_NAME%TYPE,
 P_CUST_ADDRESS  CUST_INFO.CUST_ADDRESS%TYPE,
 P_CITY          CUST_INFO.CITY%TYPE,
 P_STATE         CUST_INFO.STATE%TYPE,
 P_ZIP           CUST_INFO.ZIP%TYPE,
 P_PHONE         CUST_INFO.PHONE%TYPE
 )
IS
BEGIN
   INSERT INTO CUST_INFO (
   CUST_ID, CUST_F_NAME, CUST_L_NAME, CUST_ADDRESS, CITY,STATE, ZIP, PHONE) 
      VALUES (
   P_CUST_ID, P_CUST_F_NAME, P_CUST_L_NAME, P_CUST_ADDRESS, P_CITY, P_STATE, P_ZIP,P_PHONE
              )
END ADD_CUST;
/
```

This is my cust_info table:

```
CREATE TABLE CUST_INFO
(
 CUST_ID       NUMBER(15),
 CUST_F_NAME   VARCHAR(20),
 CUST_L_NAME   VARCHAR(20),
 CUST_ADDRESS  VARCHAR(40),
 CITY          VARCHAR(30),
 STATE         VARCHAR(30),
 ZIP           NUMBER,
 PHONE         VARCHAR(12),
 PRIMARY KEY (CUST_ID)
 );
```

I am getting errors which are not very useful at least for me. 
LINE/COL ERROR

---

15/1     PL/SQL: SQL Statement ignored
20/7     PL/SQL: ORA-00933: SQL command not properly ended
20/19    PLS-00103: Encountered the symbol "end-of-file" when expecting
  one of the following:
  ( begin case declare end exception exit for goto if loop mod
  null pragma raise return select update while with
   
   << continue close current delete fetch lock
  insert open rollback savepoint set sql execute commit forall
  merge pipe purge

Thank you.

Comment: This question is too localized, being result of a typo

Comment: [Seems to at least create without a problem](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/ac613/1).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
     CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE ADD_CUST
     (
      P_CUST_ID       CUST_INFO.CUST_ID%TYPE,
      P_CUST_F_NAME   CUST_INFO.CUST_F_NAME%TYPE,
      P_CUST_L_NAME   CUST_INFO.CUST_L_NAME%TYPE,
      P_CUST_ADDRESS  CUST_INFO.CUST_ADDRESS%TYPE,
      P_CITY          CUST_INFO.CITY%TYPE,
      P_STATE         CUST_INFO.STATE%TYPE,
      P_ZIP           CUST_INFO.ZIP%TYPE,
      P_PHONE         CUST_INFO.PHONE%TYPE
      )
      IS
      BEGIN

INSERT INTO CUST_INFO (
CUST_ID, CUST_F_NAME, CUST_L_NAME, CUST_ADDRESS, CITY,STATE, ZIP, PHONE) 
      VALUES (
P_CUST_ID, P_CUST_F_NAME, P_CUST_L_NAME, P_CUST_ADDRESS, P_CITY, P_STATE, P_ZIP,P_PHONE
             );
      END ADD_CUST;
      /
```

Just removed the brackets in between, possibly a copy paste issue; Time for a break I believe!

Comment: OH, you are right about that. Now, I have new error. I edited the original code and posted new error message.

Comment: A semicolon after the INSERT!